# Prevent letters or numbers below 0 from being entered

Tags: c++, for-loop, io

I am trying to make it so that letters or numbers below 0 cannot be entered. But if i enter a letter I get an infinite loop.

this is what i have now

```
int DiskCylCur [DiskDevices];
for (int i = 1; i<=DiskDevices; i++)
{
    int input = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number of Cylenders for Disk " <<  i << " : ";
    cin >> input;
    DiskCylCur[i] = input;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You should probably use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/).

Comment: Arrays in C++ are zero based, FYI. You should not be populating the elements from `1` to `DiskDevices` because `DiskCylCur[DiskDevices]` will stomp on the memory of that last index since it is out of range.

Comment: There can't be an infinite loop here (if we don't consider the undefined behavior because of the out-of-bound access that @Cyber mentioned), as the input is not used in the control block of the loop, you are not showing us the full code and I suspect something is happening somewhere else. Please provide a reproducible test case.

Comment: Try reading this first.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html  I don't see any possibility of infinite loop in your example, but the link should help with answering your question about ignoring undesired inputs.

Comment: For the less than zero issue, just use `unsigned`.

Comment: There is no point of using an unsigned here.

Answer (score -1):

When you enter a letter instead of number, `cout` does not read the number and letter stays in the input stream.

To detect such errors, read a string, then convert the string to an int.

```
std::string s;
cin >> s;
int input;
if ( sscanf(s.c_str(), "%d", &input) == 1 )
{
  // Got a number. Use it.
}
```

Comment: There can't be an infinite loop here, as the input is not used in the control block of the loop.

Comment: You mean cin?  I don't see anything in the example that would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @Joky and shawn1874, the infinite loop part was an oversight. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a while loop and a test.

```
bool ok = false;
while(ok) {
    if (input > 0) {
        ok = true;
    }
}
```